# HTAccess Redirect using main parameter, ignore all others

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

firstly I know and understand how to redirect based on parameters :)

My issue is that I need to redirect all links based on the supplied MenuID parameter and ignore any other information in the query string, as not all parameters are used in each web page request, e.g. menuid=2738421; is New Products

```
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products& limit=5&page=24
```

or,

```
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products&limit=20&page=3
```

or,

```
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&page=12&limit=15
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/new.html?page=x&limit=x
```

The reason for the redirection is that search-engines have indexed these pages and so I need to prettify the URLs.

Is this actually possible to create a fuzzy redirect criteria?

```
## 301 Redirects
# 301 Redirect 1 - works for this explicit URL, but need a partial result
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^new\.html$ http://www.monarchycatering.com/shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products&limit=5&page=24 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Any help gratefully taken, thank you in advance

Mark.

Comment: How do you want to prettify them? meaning what do you want your clean urls to look like. Give an example of the URL you'd like to use as the pretty URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, but StackOverflow doesn't seem to have a way to flag answers that have been replied to and need my attention.

OK, if I understand you correctly, you have an **incoming** "reduced" semi-SEF URL out in the real world (produced by your links), such as

```
http://www.domain.com/new.html&limit=5&page=24
```

("real" SEF would be something like `http://www.domain.com/new/limit/5/page/24.html`)

and you need to use .htaccess to map it to real files and more Query String information:

```
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products&limit=5&page=24
```

You want to detect `new.html` for example, and replace it by a *fixed string* `shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products&`, using the [QSA] flag to append the existing Query String on to the end?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^new\.html  /shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products [QSA]
RewriteRule  ^sale\.html  /shop.php?menuid=32424&menuref=Ja&menutitle=Products+On+Sale [QSA]
...etc...
```

I believe that a & will be stuck on the end of the rewritten address if the user supplied a non-empty Query String, but be sure to test it both ways.

P.S. It probably would have been cleaner to use "comment" to reply to my question, rather than adding another answer.

Comment: Spot-on. I knew it could be done. The URLs were a bit of a mess and too many parameters in the querystring. Thanks again and sorry for the mis-reply, not an experienced user of SO.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your starting point is and where you're trying to end up. Do you have "pretty" URLs that you want to convert into "non-pretty" Query Strings that your scripts can actually digest?

> The reason for the redirection is that search-engines have indexed
>   these pages and so I need to prettify the URLs.

If the search engines have already indexed the Query String non-pretty version, they'll have to now re-index with pretty URLs. Ditto for all your customers' bookmarks.

If you want to generate "pretty" links within your site, and decode them (in .htaccess) upon re-entry to non-pretty Query Strings, that should work. Your customers' existing bookmarks should even continue to work, while the search engines will replace the non-pretty with the pretty URLs.

Answer (score -1):

and thanks for the interest in my question...

I have rewritten parts of my website and Google still has references to the old MenuID parameter and shop.php configuration, but now I rewriten the Query to a prettier format, e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=2738421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products&limit=5&page=24
```

is now

```
http://www.domain.com/new.html&limit=5&page=24
```

The pages represent product categories, and so needed to be displayed in a more meaningful manner. Customer bookmarking is not an issue, as long as I can redirect the pages.

I hope that makes sense, best wishes,

Mark.

Comment: How did you do it? This is not a valid answer.